# mySQL calculation giving incorrect data

Tags: mysql

I have written the below query and get good data,
What is the correct way to then have the gross hire less the discount show as net hire?? the script I wrote gives me a null value for 1 branch and I know this is incorrect?

```
SELECT branch_name, gross_hire_$, discount_$
FROM m_rental R, m_vehicle V, m_branch B
WHERE r.rego_no = v.rego_no
AND v.branch_code = b.branch_code
GROUP BY b.branch_code
ORDER BY branch_name
```

Comment: Can `discount_$` be **`null`**?

Comment: Yes discount can be null

Comment: There's this great site for sql examples: sqlfiddle.com  if you build a schema and add some example data, it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your query won't throw *ambiguous column* error, this can work out for you. If you know that the discount can be null, use ifnull() while doing aggregates. If you are doing sums, then you can use sum(ifnull(discount,0)) but if you are doing averages and you want averages for non-zero records only then you'll have to do something like this:

```
sum(case when discount is not null then discount else 0 end)/
sum(case when discount is not null then 1 else 0 end)
```

But in the current scenario, the following should work out fine.

```
select branch_name, sum(ifnull(gross_hire,0)) as gross_hire,
sum(ifnull(discount,0)) as discount from m_rental r, 
m_vehicle v, m_branch b  where r.rego_no = v.rego_no 
and v.brand_code = b.branch_code group by b.branch_code order by branch_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform arithmetic in the column list of a `SELECT`, and anytime you have a column which *might* be **`null`** (and where you can replace **`null`** with some non-null value) you can use the SQL `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT branch_name, gross_hire_$, discount_$, (gross_hire_$ - COALESCE(discount_$, 0)) AS net_hire_$
  FROM m_rental R, m_vehicle V, m_branch B
  WHERE r.rego_no = v.rego_no
    AND v.branch_code = b.branch_code
  GROUP BY b.branch_code
  ORDER BY branch_name
```

should serve your purpose. The call `COALESCE(discount_$, 0)` returns the value of `discount_$` *unless it is **`null`***, in which case it returns `0`.

Note that I have not attempted to sum any columns, but the principle still holds.